# Array won't fill in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am currently working on schedule list for one company and I am really desperate after few hours of trying to figure out what the duck is messing up.

```
$schedule = [];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
   FROM schedule s 
   INNER JOIN workers w 
   ON s.worker_id = w.id BETWEEN [date1] AND [date2]");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if(($row['s.time'] >= '8:00') && ($row['s.time'] < '20:00')) {
    if($schedule[$row['s.date']]['info']['name'] == '') {
      $schedule[$row['s.date']]['info']['name'] 
           = $row['w.name']; // Just one worker
    } else {
       $schedule[$row['s.date']]['info']['name'] .= ',' . $row['name']; 
           // IF there is one or more workers, "join" them together by comma
    } 
  }
```

**NO**

- This is not the actual code, I just rewrote the while loop with if conditions
- I am unable to modify the table

**YES**

- It only returns one worker
- I tried yelling at it
- I tried many conditions (empty,isset etc.)

I am not quite sure but I think I need to initialize the **$schedule['Wed']['info']** first, but it will be pain in the butt.

Comment: please provide input array and the sample array you want...

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated you should use MySQLi or PDO.. Beside mysql_fetch_array doesnt return aliased table field names.. using `SELECT * FROM schedule s` doesn't mean you need to access them as `s.time` in PHP

Comment: I wonder what does `$string1 > $string2` give you?

Comment: It returns only one, and it is the last one?

Answer (score 0):

> This is not the actual code

We can only advise based on [the code you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

While there is an awful lot wrong with the code, the reason its not looping is that the SELECT statement is unparseable. The *problem* is that you have no visibility of the SELECT statement failing in your code. There is no error checking in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
if(($row['s.time'] >= '8:00') && ($row['s.time'] < '20:00')) {
    if(in_array($row['w.name'], $schedule)) {  // Checking if the value already exists in array.
      $schedule[][$row['s.date']]['info']['name'] 
           = $row['w.name']; // Just one worker
    } else {
       $schedule[][$row['s.date']]['info']['name'] .= ',' . $row['name']; 
           // IF there is one or more workers, "join" them together by comma
    }
}
```

then `print_r($schedule);die;`  and check. You should get all the data in the array.